# Bootstrap 3 .img-responsive images are not responsive images inside links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am use Bootstrap 3 and have a problem. Some of my images in row responsive normal, but images with links on insta and vk are not responsive. The size of images are 40x40

Code below

```css
.navbar-default-footer {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

div.col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-xs-4 img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.footer_text {
  font-size: 5px;
  color: #708090;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default-footer" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <img src="images/Originals/example2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Ищи меня в Instagram"><img src="images/insta_40x40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Ищи меня VK"><img src="images/vk_40x40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <img src="images/Originals/example2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          <p class="footer_text">
            Свадебные прически в Виннице. Людмила Кулик. Все права защищены, любое копирование и использование материала запрещено без согласия автора.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks all for help!

Comment: `but images with links on insta and vk are not responsive` What do you mean?

Comment: they are not change they size

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You speak almost as if you're putting HMTL/images **into** Instagram/VK ?

Comment: sorry, img those are inside <code><a></code> elements

Comment: Have you inspected the images to see if there is CSS overwriting the image CSS?

Comment: yep, in navbar footer i have 1 img in first .col , 2 in second and 1 in third.  img from first and third .col are responsive, second - no

Answer (score 0):

It's because `a` elements are `display: inline;` by default. Set the `a` elements to be `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`.